# Authentication with connection string User Id and not App pool account

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application which is connected to a Database through Entity Framework.

I am using a specific application pool account and I am also specifying a user account in my connection string "User Id=XXX;Password=YYY".

My problem is that my application is using the app pool account when trying connecting to the Database instead of using my connection string credentials.

Comment: It would help if you provided the full connection string you're using, along with the code where you are using it so that we can try and fault-find for you.

Comment: my problem is so simple I don't even know what to show you : at the first entity query, I received an exception : {"Cannot open database \"XXX\" requested by the login. The login failed.\r\nLogin failed for user 'YYY\\YYY'."} Where YYY\YYY is my app pool account. My connection string is : connectionString="xxx ;provider connection string=&quot;data source=xxx\xxx;initial catalog=xxx; User ID=zzz\zzz;Password=oooo;Trusted_Connection=False;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;"

Comment: "Login failed for user 'YYY\\YYY" is the key piece of information there.  That usually means it's connecting fine and then when it tries to authenticate the DB is saying it doesn't recognise the user.  This could be in two places: 1) Instance "login" - this is the a user account to log onto the DB server in the first place.  That login then gets mapped to 2) Database-level "user".  I would suggest it is the "login" at the instance level, so double-check the username/password you're using in the instance "security\login" section